# Django list_display highest value ManyToMany Field

Tags: python, django, list, django-admin

I want to know how I can display the "highest value" from my ManyToMany Field in the admin. This is my `models.py` file:

```
class Personal(models.Model):
    lastname  = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    degree = models.ManyToManyField('Degree')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname

class Degree(models.Model):
    name_degree = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Degree', max_length = 200, blank = False)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_degree
```

In my backend, I have created different types of Degree's, all with a "ranking". In my case, the highest degree you can have is "Doctoral Degree", with a rank of "6". [image: Backed Admin List for Education]

So if a User is creating himself in "Personal" he will have the option to select all the Degree's he has achieved. But for my Personal list, I just to want to see the highest one, e.g. if the User selects "Bachelor's Degree" and "Master's Degree", the Personal list should only contain "Master's Degree", because 5 > 4.

Someone with an idea on how my `admin.py` file should look like?

```
class PersonalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('lastname', 'firstname', ) # 'degree'
```

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method in your `ModelAdmin` to calculate the maximum degree:

```
class PersonalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('lastname', 'firstname', 'highest_degree')

    @admin.display(description='Highest degree')
    def highest_degree(self, obj):
        deg = Degree.objects.filter(personal=obj).first()
        if deg:
            return deg.name_degree
        return None
```

This is however quite inefficient if we want to render a lot of `Personal`s, since that will require an extra query *per* item.

We can let the database do the work for us with a [*subquery expression*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

class PersonalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('lastname', 'firstname', 'highest_degree')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Personal.objects.annotate(
            highest_degree=Subquery(
                Degree.objects.filter(
                    personal=OuterRef('pk')
                ).order_by('-rank').values('name_degree')[:1]
            )
        )

    @admin.display(description='Highest degree')
    def highest_degree(self, obj):
        return obj.highest_degree
```

This will calculate the name of the degrees in *bulk*.

Comment: I get this Error in the PersonalAdmin: ``` admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'highest_degree', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PersonalAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'data.Personal'.```

Comment: @schuhesindbequemer: if you work with the annotation, you need to remove the `highest_degree` method.

Comment: @schuhesindbequemer: no, the. Exactly which of the two solutions do you use?

Comment: the second one, I thought that was better

Comment: @schuhesindbequemer: I forgot the method, can you add this to the `ModelAdmin` (the last function)